# Don't understand why these bitwise operations aren't working

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, zero

i wrote this simple code: bitwise operators. The output is very strange.
If I change bitwise operation (mask) from `1<<i` to `1>>i`  **and** is always 0. See output.

```
reg=31272
#binreg=111101000101000
print bin(reg)
for i in range(0,15):
    mask=1<<i
    c=reg & mask
    print "i:", i ,"c:", c ,"-", bin(c)
```

Output:

```
bitwise_little_endian():
 0b111101000101000
 i: 0 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 1 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 2 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 3 c: 8 - 0b1000
 i: 4 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 5 c: 32 - 0b100000
 i: 6 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 7 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 8 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 9 c: 512 - 0b1000000000
 i: 10 c: 0 - 0b0
 i: 11 c: 2048 - 0b100000000000
 i: 12 c: 4096 - 0b1000000000000
 i: 13 c: 8192 - 0b10000000000000
 i: 14 c: 16384 - 0b100000000000000


bitwise_big_endian():
0b111101000101000
i: 0 c: 0 - 0b0
i: 1 c: 0 - 0b0
i: 2 c: 0 - 0b0
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: Why would you expect the result *not* to be 0? `1 >> i` is 0 for any positive `i`, and `anything & 0` is 0.

Comment: Oh, because 1<<N shift left but 1>>N shift right. So, after last bit (16 bits) the padding is always zero because the arch is little endian. Is this explanation correct?

Comment: Nope. I'm not sure what you were trying to say there, but endianness doesn't come into things, and it's not 16-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewritten version of your code, modified to print the results in a little more readable fashion (Note that the use of `bit_length()` requires Python 2.7+).

```
reg = 31272  # 0b111101000101000
num_bits = reg.bit_length()
print('reg:  0b{:0{width}b}'.format(reg, width=num_bits))

for i in range(num_bits):  # Test each bit in "reg".
    mask = 1 << i
    c = reg & mask
    print('i: {:>2}, c: {:6,} - 0b{:0{width}b}'.format(i, c, c, width=num_bits))
```

Output:

```
reg:  0b111101000101000
i:  0, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  1, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  2, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  3, c:      8 - 0b000000000001000
i:  4, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  5, c:     32 - 0b000000000100000
i:  6, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  7, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  8, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i:  9, c:    512 - 0b000001000000000
i: 10, c:      0 - 0b000000000000000
i: 11, c:  2,048 - 0b000100000000000
i: 12, c:  4,096 - 0b001000000000000
i: 13, c:  8,192 - 0b010000000000000
i: 14, c: 16,384 - 0b100000000000000
```

The output seems to make sense to me. You need to understand the the result of the masking operation can be a relatively large number because it just isolates the bit being tested, but the bit is still in its original position in the internal binary representation of the integer value being tested.